# Issue with hasNext()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have 2 issues with the hasNext() function of the Scanner class.

My loop should  have 4 iterations, but  my loop is infinite instead.

Here is the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "Munich     London      Paris   New_York";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(t);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("GOOD");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a definition of the **hasNext()** function from official Oracle documentation :

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

So, what they mean with: **"The scanner does not advance past any input."** ?

Comment: Class names should begin with an uppercase i.e. `Main`, per Java naming conventions.

Comment: You call `sc.hasNext()` to check whether there's a next token, but you never call `sc.next()` to actually advance to the next token; you'll be stuck at the first token forever.

Comment: You're not calling `next()`?

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: Personally, I'd split the string and loop over the array. Is there a specific reason to use a Scanner, if you're not going to call next()?

Comment: my code is just a test

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `next()`. Also, make sure you use a delimiter of `\s+`.

Please note that class names should begin with an uppercase letter.

```java
/* Filename: Main.java */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "Munich     London      Paris   New_York";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(t).useDelimiter("\\s+");

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Munich
London
Paris
New_York
```

Comment: The file now needs to be renamed to Main.java, as well

Comment: Also you don't need that much space between each word. You could just put one space unless you want the code to be more clear.

Comment: I would have upvoted, but I don't buy the need to set a different separator.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yeah, sorry. It seems the default delimiter checks for ALL whitespace. So this is really not needed.